# Change the color of a SVG component in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a SVG component which is like the following:

```js
       <Svg width={svgSize} height={svgSize}>
          <Defs>
            <LinearGradient
              x1="0%"
              y1="100%"
              x2="100%"
              y2="0%"
              id="gradient">
              {
                linearGradient.map((item, index) => (
                  <Stop
                    key={index}
                    offset={item.stop}
                    stopColor={item.color}
                  />
                ))
              }
            </LinearGradient>
          </Defs>
          
          <Path
            strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
            stroke={backgroundTrackColor}
            fill="none"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            d={`M${startPoint.x},${startPoint.y} A ${radius},${radius},0,${startRadian - openingRadian >= Math.PI ? '1' : '0'},1,${endPoint.x},${endPoint.y}`}
          />
          <Path
            strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
            stroke="url(#gradient)"
            fill="none"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            d={`M${startPoint.x},${startPoint.y} A ${radius},${radius},0,${startRadian - currentRadian >= Math.PI ? '1' : '0'},1,${curPoint.x},${curPoint.y}`}
          />
          <Circle
            cx={curPoint.x}
            cy={curPoint.y}
            r={buttonRadius}
            fill={buttonFillColor || buttonBorderColor}
            stroke={buttonBorderColor}
            strokeWidth={buttonStrokeWidth}
            {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
          />
        </Svg>
```

Now, this looks like the following :

[image]

But i don't want to use LinearGradient color in this slider. I want fixed colors like this:

[image]

How can i achieve the following with fixed color?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `LinearGradient` component coming from?

If you use [react-native-linear-gradient](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-linear-gradient) you can use the `locations` prop to assign color [stops](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-linear-gradient#locations) and add an extra stop for each so there's no fade, something like:

```
<LinearGradient
  start={{x: 0.0, y: 0.0}} end={{x: 1.0, y: 1.0}}
  locations={[0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3]}
  colors={['#000', '#000', '#111', '#111', '#222' '#222', '#333']}
>
  ...
</LinearGradient>
```

Comment: LinearGradient is coming from 'react-native-svg' @bryce

Comment: Looks like that library only supports two colors since you explicitly define `x1`/`y1`/`x2`/`y2`. I would switch to the library I mentioned for your use case as it supports a list-based prop instead.

Comment: Can you show me how to used those fixed colors with 'react-native-linear-gradient' if i use that? @bryce

Comment: Sure @TanmoySarker, updated answer.